# Complex Analysis and Topology

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate who is interested in topology and in the future wants to have a PhD in the field of Topology. I know the basics of holomorphic functions, contour integration and elliptic functions. There is this paper ([https://gauss.math.yale.edu/~ws442/complex.pdf](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/%7Ews442/complex.pdf)) that I want to read about Riemann surfaces, but I am not sure whether it will be useful to me in the future in the area of topology. Should I read it or focus my interest on topology related subjects?

Comment: Read everything

Comment: That appears to be a good book from a skim, though I would hesitate against publicly posting links unless you have authorization to do so. In any case, it's an intro to Riemann Surfaces text (that apparently is also an intro to complex analysis?) written with a very analytic flavor. While Riemann surfaces are definitely fascinating topological spaces, being dimension 1 complex manifolds and having their geometry and topology interact nontrivially, I would have to know your background and interests in much more depth to have any confidence in recommending for or against such a text.

Comment: @user27182 Unless you've unlocked the secret to immortality (and if you have: pray tell!) I'm not sure this advice is at all helpful. Surely a topologist will run into Riemann Surfaces at some point, but it does not mean one has to read *everything* about them (especially from a book with such an analytic flavor)

Comment: It strongly depends on *what* topology you'd like to do, but maybe you don't know yet, as you're too early in your education. Maybe it's more a question of who your intended PhD-supervisor will be and the kind of research that person is interested in.

Comment: For a rather specific branch of low dimensional geometric topology (hyperbolic structures on 2-manifold and 3-manifolds), I would say that yes, one does need to learn many of the fine details of Riemann surfaces, with emphasis on quasiconformal maps. But on the other hand, even for that rather specific branch, you're more than likely pick up what you need when you need it. You'd probably do better to pick up a book on knot theory.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :) but @user27182 I disagree with your view of reading everything; which I see as inefficient and time-consuming. Unless you are immortal :)